# buffer geometry mesh not loading when using web worker

Tags: javascript, three.js, web-worker

I could transfer my geometry into buffer geometry and found mesh good with both geometry and material but model is not showing up in window.

Here is my code:

```
var myWorker = new Worker("js/respond.js");
myWorker.postMessage("horse.js");

myWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
    geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    var colorattribute = new THREE.BufferAttribute(e.data.color, 3, false);
    var uv = new THREE.BufferAttribute(e.data.uv, 3, false);//created buffer attribute with worker data
    var normal = new THREE.BufferAttribute(e.data.normal, 3, false);
    var position = new THREE.BufferAttribute(e.data.position, 3, false);
    var morph = new THREE.BufferAttribute(e.data.morphAttributes, 3, false);
    geometry.addAttribute('color', colorattribute);
    geometry.addAttribute('uv', uv);
    geometry.addAttribute('normal', normal);
    geometry.addAttribute('position', position);
    geometry.addGroup(e.data.groups[0].start, e.data.groups[0].count, e.data.groups[0].materialIndex);
    geometry.morphAttributes.position = [];
    geometry.morphAttributes.position.push(morph);
    //console.log(e.data.morphAttributes);

    // mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(mesh);
    // clip = THREE.AnimationClip.CreateFromMorphTargetSequence('static', geometry.morphAttributes, 30);
    console.log(geometry);
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:  0xffffff, morphTargets: true}));
    console.log(mesh);
    scene.add(mesh);
```

Comment: Your question is missing info about what library are you using for the geomethry. For most libraryes, there is a special tags and people who know about them follow those tags. Adding correct library tags is much more important than adding correct language tags. I took the liberty of adding correct tag. Also please note that only either one `.` or three `...` dots are valid in English sentence, not eight of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use libraries like THREE.js in your web worker.

What you *can* do is construct your geometry in a worker, and then feed that into THREE.js later. From the web worker, you can return an object containing `TypedArrays` of `UInt32Arrays` and `Float32Arrays` as needed to fill in all of the attributes.

This will result in a performance boost because the data is already structured in the format `THREE.BufferGeometry` wants.